# Android Studio how to get Intent into Service from WallpaperManager

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I initialized a WallpaperService to use it with the WallpaperManager.

My Code looks like this right now:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(WallpaperManager.ACTION_CHANGE_LIVE_WALLPAPER);
            intent.putExtra(WallpaperManager.EXTRA_LIVE_WALLPAPER_COMPONENT, new ComponentName(this, WallpaperService.class));
            startActivity(intent);
```

My question is, how can I add a color into the Intent and use it in the WallpaperService?
The first idea i got was to add

```
            intent.putExtra("backGroundColor", mDefaultColor);
```

But this value isn't reachable in the WallpaperService.

The current Service looks like this:

```
public class GameOfLifeWallpaperService extends WallpaperService {

    @Override
    public Engine onCreateEngine() {
        return new GameOfLifeWallpaperEngine();
    }

    private class GameOfLifeWallpaperEngine extends Engine {
        int backgroundColor;
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get the intent and it's extras/bundle, you need to Override the `onStartCommand` method inside the service.

There you will have access to the intent and should use a bundle to get the extras.

```
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        int color = (int) bundle.get("backGroundColor");

        return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
```

Notice that the method should return one of the START_STICKY_COMPATIBILITY, START_STICKY, START_NOT_STICKY, or START_REDELIVER_INTENT values.

Sometimes the intent data can get lost due to an error. If you want to redeliver the same intent data, use START_REDELIVER_INTEN.

You can read more about it on the [android.developers.com](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService#onStartCommand(android.content.Intent,%20int,%20int)) website.